# adding new item to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to add a new item (a placeholder) to an array -- to each node

My array looks as follow:

[image]

And I wanna add the following key/value under `value`  **Year: "2010"**

I have tried `*json1.push("Year", "2010")*` but that just creates a new entry

Comment: Please, post code, not images of code.

Comment: It would help if you could also post an example of the way you want your array to look when you're done.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular i just wanna add "Year", "2010" to each node in my array... the image is just the console output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add it to the first object on the array, use
`json1[0]["year"] = "2010"`

Comment: @Boluwatife thanks!! it add to the first object.. how do i add to each object?

Comment: Loop through the array.

Comment: ```for(let i =0; i < json1.length; i++) json1[i]["year"] = "2010"